# Quran in Arabic and Only Translation

Tags: quran

Asalam mualikum. 
My question about Quran in Arabic and only English translation " without Arabic word's" are co equal?
Can we call only translation Quran?
Is it also compulsory to touch with ablution "only translation?
And if any reference from the time of Sahaba please provide with answer....

Comment: Quran is only Arabic

Answer (score -1):

The translated version of Quran is **NOT** Quran, it is a try to translate the quranic verses, and convey its meanings in a manner that non Arabic speakers can understand. so it is never equal to Quran itself.

Quran is sent down in Arabic,

> Indeed, We have sent it down as an Arabic Qur'an that you might
>   understand. **12-2**

many examples from Quran translation show how other languages lack power while trying to deliver the original meaning in the Arabic Quran.

For touching the Quranic translation, if the translation is not considered to be equal to Quran so why to treat it as Quran? and why not?

**Ibnu baz** replied to a similar question that The translated version of Quran is treated as the Tafseer of Quran books. and even non-muslims can read it without Tahara or ablution.

**I read it because I can't read Arabic:**

I think from a niyya (intention) perspective, people who try to read the translation are after the reward of reading Quran, please recall that reading Quran requires pondering, thinking and speculation upon the different verses of the Holy Quran, So what I guess is that if you have the intention to read a translation then this is equivalent by intention to reading the Arabic Quran, again this is my personal opinion here and **Allah** **knows best**